# When loading a .BMP image using SDL on visual studios 2012, it only shows a frame

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, sdl

I'm trying to make a game on visual studio 2012. I'm using SDL and I've set everything up correctly due to this tutorial: http://sdltutorials.com/sdl-tutorial-basics

I did look for other solutions on google: (1) place the image files in the project file. And, (2) place the images with the .exe program. A window does show but its black with no images. Both of these solutions failed. I'm on the edge of giving up on using visual studio 2012 for anything now. As for the code, I got the sources at the link I posted above. Thanks :)

EDIT:

When I build the project, its a success.

Im also using SDL-devel-1.2.15/SDL version 1.2.15.

My os system is windows 8.1 if that helps.

Here's the code for a short version of this example:

```
#include "SDL.h"

int main( int argc, char* args[] )
{
    //The images
    SDL_Surface* hello = NULL;
    SDL_Surface* screen = NULL;

     //Start SDL
    SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING );

    //Set up screen
    screen = SDL_SetVideoMode( 640, 480, 32, SDL_SWSURFACE );

    //Load image
    hello = SDL_LoadBMP( "hello.bmp" );

    //Apply image to screen
    SDL_BlitSurface( hello, NULL, screen, NULL );

    //Update Screen
    SDL_Flip( screen );

    //Pause
    SDL_Delay( 2000 );

    //Free the loaded image
    SDL_FreeSurface( hello );

    //Quit SDL
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

The image shows. It was the code example from the website I posted. Can anyone find out what's wrong with his code(not the code I posted here. The code examples I shared in the website)?

Comment: Maybe it's your code?

Comment: Add some error checking to your code and find out what exactly is failing, then post your code here explaining that.

Comment: @Retired Ninja: Everything compiles correctly. I do get this file when I compile and look in my project directory, stderr.txt

Comment: Not sure if you've tried, but the image needs to be in the same directory as the `.vcxproj` file for your project.

Comment: @dauphic: I tried that solution, too. I even tried to save the images again as .BMP files. Is it because I'm using another version of SDL? Im running out of ideas.

Comment: **Post your code**. "Everything compiles correctly." Even if program compiles, it doesn't mean it *WORKS* correctly.

Comment: its in the link above. http://www.sdltutorials.com/Data/Posts/106//Win32-Source.zip

Comment: @cyberspace009: The code you linked does not load any images, which means it is the code you're talking about. It also renders nothing, and doesn't even swap buffers. If you want help, you should probably stop wasting time and post actual code you're having problem with. Also, I'd advise to look for tutorials elsewhere (code quality in this tutorial is (IMO) very poor). If I remember correctly, documentation on libsdl org had occasional code samples.

Comment: @SigTerm: Well, (1): there's so many files i will not post here. (2): I will only post the code with a .rar file because its impossible to load my code in this forum. Take a look: https://www.mediafire.com/?746lh8o1b2w5tiv

Comment: @SigTerm: if the programming is horrible, maybe that is what's causing it.

Comment: Reduce your code to a short self-contained example of only the thing you're having a problem with and then post that.  Links to external sites go stale and that makes the question and any answers useless for someone with the same problem in the future.

Comment: @Retired Ninja: Good idea. I'll do a quick example and post it here.

Comment: Well, I've come to a conclusion that this guy's coding is not well since I was following that tutorial. Oh well, time to learn from Lazy Foo's SDL tutorial ro maybe libsdl.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can anyone find out what's wrong with his code(not the code I posted here.

The code in tutorial (Win32_Sources.zip) you linked never calls `SDL_Flip` So even if you DO draw something on screen, you'll never see it.

Another problem is that this dude hasn't read SDL documentation, and attempts to free framebuffer (allocated with `SDL_SetVideoMode`) with `SDL_FreeSurface`. According to documentation, [you shouldn't do that](http://sdl.beuc.net/sdl.wiki/SDL_SetVideoMode), because framebuffer is released by `SDL_Quit`.

(opinion)In addition to that I think his coding style is rather very poor - the has that "let's make a class for everything"(i.e. he loves OOP too much) problem, that some newbies have. Making separate *.cpp for a single function doesn't look like a good idea to me (it is 10..15 lines of code, for ****'s sake), I don't quite agree with his choice of CodeBlocks for project's IDE/build system, the code also kinda reminds me of MFC or Microsoft coding examples (where classes are named CSomething, etc). Overall, the guy looks like another newbie me so I don't think learning from him is a good idea.(/opinion)

I'd recommend to read SDL documentation instead of following tutorials (like this one). SDL is rather simple by itself, and its documentation contains short/simple examples which are normally written in C, which means there will be no OOP madness as in this guy's example.

For a build system or IDE on windows platform I'd suggest to use Visual Studio express (instead of codeblocks), however you should also learn some cross-platform build tool like CMake or qMake (part of Qt 4 or Qt 5). Learning those tools will make your life easier should you ever decide to transition to linux or something similar.

For a realtively good/clean C++ coding style, you should take a look at [Qt 4/5](http://qt-project.org/) source code, tutorials and examples. Qt will be also useful shall you ever need GUI toolkit. Also consider trying OpenGL. Pure SDL is fine if you want to do MS-Dos style demos or software renderer, but OpenGL can do certain things faster.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider upgrading to SDL2 and using a different set of tutorials like these that don't look too bad: http://twinklebeardev.blogspot.com/p/sdl-20-tutorial-index.html

If not you can use the same `GetCurrentDirectory` code to figure out what directory it is expecting the file to be in.

Here's a simple SDL2 example that loads and displays a bitmap.  You can put breakpoints in the error checking code so you can see what's wrong if it fails.  Make sure you're building a console style program so the errors have somewhere to print.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "SDL.h"

#pragma comment(lib, "sdl2.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "sdl2main.lib")

int main(int argc, char* args[])
{
    const std::string bmpFilename("test.bmp");

    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);

    SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow("Test", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 640, 480, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    if(!window)
    {
        std::cerr << "Could not create window!\n";
        return 0;
    }

    SDL_Renderer *renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED | SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC);
    if(!renderer)
    {
        std::cerr << "Could not create renderer!\n";
        return 0;
    }

    SDL_Surface* bmp = SDL_LoadBMP(bmpFilename.c_str());
    if(!bmp)
    {
        char workingDirectory[_MAX_PATH];
        GetCurrentDirectory(sizeof(workingDirectory), workingDirectory);
        std::string fullPath(std::string(workingDirectory) + "\\" + bmpFilename);
        std::cerr << "Could not load " << fullPath << "!\n";
        return 0;
    }
    SDL_Texture *texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, bmp);
    if(!texture)
    {
        std::cerr << "Could not create texture!\n";
        return 0;
    }
    SDL_FreeSurface(bmp);

    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
    SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texture, NULL, NULL);
    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);

    SDL_Delay(2000);

    SDL_DestroyTexture(texture);
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);

    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: will SDL2 provide more tutorials? I heard that SDL2 is new and not a lot of tutorials are around for it.